# Formating sqlplus output into separate columns

Tags: database, bash, oracle, sqlplus

I need to make a query from a bash script. It is asking the database to return two columns, but sqlplus is formatting them into a single column. I would prefer to have two as it would simplify the parsing I need to do to solve my problem. Currently I have this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s user/password@server.com:1521/ZABBIX <<-EOF >testoutput2

set feedback off
set long 2000000
set linesize 500
set trimspool on
set longc 500
set pagesize 0
set echo off 

select SERVER_NAME, INSTANCE_ID from cmdb.VW_CMDB_SERVICE_INFRASTRUCTURE where MODULES like 'WMS/FAIL';

EOF
```

To be perfectly honest I am not too sure what all the sets are doing, but the current output looks like this:

```
czcholspc000150
beboop1

czcholspc000182
beborp1


czcholspc000025
delanp1

czcholspc000182
demoep3

czcholspc000063
demoep1

czcholspc000100
demorp1

czcholspc000150
deunnp1

czcholspc000860
deunnp1

czcholspc000025
dkgrep1

czstlls059
glblep1
```

It merges the columns into one. I would ideally want it in two columns separated by either a whitespace or a comma.